# Parsing from 3 links at the same time htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I parse command history of games for 2014,2013,2015 years. 
They have the same structure. But the links are different.

```
var fourthDoc = htmlWeb.Load("http://soccer.net/2014-2015/results/");
var fifthDoc =  htmlWeb.Load("http://soccer.net/2013-2014/results/");
var sixthDoc =  htmlWeb.Load("http://soccer.net/2015-2016/results/");
```

Its how I parse data:

```
       var Games =
                fourthDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("@class = 'abc'").Select(a => new Game()
                {
                    Date = a.SelectNodes("./a/div/div[1]/span").Single().InnerText.Trim(),
                    //....
                });
```

Model:

```
public class Game
    {
            public int Id {get;set;}
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public string FirstTeam { get; set; }
            public string SecondTeam { get; set; }
    }
```

How to combine the three links in one path?
For example

```
var fourthDoc = htmlWeb.Load("http://soccer.net/2014-2015/results/"+"http://soccer.net/2013-2014/results/"+"http://soccer.net/2015-2016/results/");
```

Comment: Please explain your question more; "How to combine the two links in one path"

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm not sure but I think** you want to give an array of strings ( urls ) and parse all the data which will come from the website.

You should try something like that;

```
        List<string> urls = new List<string>
                            {
                                "http://soccer.net/2014-2015/results/",
                                "http://soccer.net/2013-2014/results/",
                                "http://soccer.net/2015-2016/results/"
                            };

        List<Games> games = new List<Games>();
        foreach (string url in urls)
        {
            var currentData = htmlWeb.Load("url");

            var currentListOfGames =
                currentData.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("@class = 'abc'").Select(a => new Game()
                                                                                   {
                                                                                       Date = a.SelectNodes("./a/div/div[1]/span").Single().InnerText.Trim(),
                                                                                       //....
                                                                                   });

            games.AddRange(currentListOfGames);
        }
```

Because htmlagilitypack's htmlweb.Load method accepts only one url per request.